# How to sum columns between two dataframes using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sum columns between two tables: "diario" and "mensal" to update the values on "count" and "sum". My problem is: the result for some columns is empty.

It's working for archives with less then 100 rows, but I need to do it for "diario" with 4800 rows while "mensal" has 5642 rows.

Here is the code and the tables examples:

```
diario = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/diario.csv')
mensal = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/mensal.csv')

mensal_ini = mensal.copy()
mensal.loc[(mensal['imsi'].isin(diario['imsi'])) & (mensal['operadora'].isin(diario['operadora'])), "sum"] += diario['sum']
mensal.loc[(mensal['imsi'].isin(diario['imsi'])) & (mensal['operadora'].isin(diario['operadora'])), "count"] += diario['count']

mensal = pd.concat([mensal, diario]).drop_duplicates(subset=['imsi','operadora'])

f = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/mensal_result.csv", 'w')
f.writelines(mensal.to_csv(index=False))
f.close()
```

Table 1 - "Diario"

```
imsi operadora sum count
xxx1 yyy       10 1
xxx2 yyy       20 3
```

Table 2 - "Mensal"

```
imsi operadora sum count
xxx1 yyy       30 2
xxx1 abc       25 4
xxx3 yyy       14 2
```

Table 3 - "Result"

```
imsi operadora sum count
xxx1 yyy       empty empty
xxx1 abc       25 4
xxx2 yyy       20 3
xxx3 yyy       14 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `concat` then `groupby`:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby(['imsi','operadora'], as_index=False).sum()
```

Output:

```
   imsi operadora  sum  count
0  xxx1       abc   25      4
1  xxx1       yyy   40      3
2  xxx2       yyy   20      3
3  xxx3       yyy   14      2
```